# OutOfRangeError in scaling up Tensor2Tensor Transformer TPU tutorial

Tags: google-compute-engine, tensor2tensor

I followed the T2T Transformer "Train a language model" example and it worked for 10 training step. However, when scaling up to 250,000 steps I get an OutOfRange error (below). Is this a problem with parsing or something else?

```
INFO:tensorflow:Init TPU system
INFO:tensorflow:Starting infeed thread controller.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting outfeed thread controller.
INFO:tensorflow:Enqueue next (100) batch(es) of data to infeed.
INFO:tensorflow:Dequeue next (100) batch(es) of data from outfeed.
WARNING:tensorflow:

Error occurred during infeed/outfeed.  This may be due to a compile error in the main session.  Waiting for a short time for the main session to come back.
  End of sequence
         [[Node: input_pipeline_task0/while/IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[_class=["loc:@input_pipeline_task0/while/InfeedQueue/split/4"], output_shapes=[[64,1], [64,256,1,1], [64,256], [64,256], [64,256,1,1]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32], _device="/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](input_pipeline_task0/while/IteratorGetNext/Enter, ^input_pipeline_task0/while/Identity)]]

Caused by op 'input_pipeline_task0/while/IteratorGetNext', defined at:
  File "/usr/local/bin/t2t-trainer", line 32, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/usr/local/bin/t2t-trainer", line 28, in main
    t2t_trainer.main(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensor2tensor/bin/t2t_trainer.py", line 359, in main
    execute_schedule(exp)
  ...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 729, in enqueue_ops_fn
    features, labels = inputs.features_and_labels()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2766, in features_and_labels
    return _Inputs._parse_inputs(self._iterator.get_next())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 373, in get_next
    name=name)), self._output_types,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 1745, in iterator_get_next
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence
         [[Node: input_pipeline_task0/while/IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[_class=["loc:@input_pipeline_task0/while/InfeedQueue/split/4"], output_shapes=[[64,1], [64,256,1,1], [64,256], [64,256], [64,256,1,1]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32], _device="/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](input_pipeline_task0/while/IteratorGetNext/Enter, ^input_pipeline_task0/while/Identity)]]

ERROR:tensorflow:Feed error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OutOfRangeError: End of sequence
         [[Node: input_pipeline_task0/while/IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[_class=["loc:@input_pipeline_task0/while/InfeedQueue/split/4"], output_shapes=[[64,1], [64,256,1,1], [64,256], [64,256], [64,256,1,1]], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32], _device="/job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](input_pipeline_task0/while/IteratorGetNext/Enter, ^input_pipeline_task0/while/Identity)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: Step was cancelled by an explicit call to `Session::Close()`.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the authors of the Tensor2Tensor library here.

Short answer: reduce `--eval_steps`.

Long answer:

Unfortunately, the `TPUEstimator`, the library we use under the hood to run on TPU, does not catch `OutOfRangeError` when you run out of input data. During training it's not a problem because the input data is infinite (we call repeat on the input `tf.data.Dataset`). However, during evaluation, you want to do 1 pass over the data, which means that you need to set `--eval_steps` correctly so that you don't exhaust the input data. Hopefully `TPUEstimator` will soon handle catching the error so that you don't have to figure out how many eval steps you have to run.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you’ve follow the instructions in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/transformer#train_a_language_model).
The relevant error from the output is the line for “OutOfRangeError” on “End of sequence”. This error is the signal used by input pipeline to let upper stream know that there is no more data to process.

You need to ensure there is data for the TPU to process by making sure of the following:
The TPU has access to training data (e.g. GCS bucket)
There is no typo in the paths in the command, and most importantly,
That your data set is either large or you have a dataset.repeat() to ensure your training data doesn't run out before your TPU has completed the configured number of training steps.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that the example in the tutorial generates a lot of train data, but very little eval data. To increase the number of eval steps, more eval data needs to be generated.